# Executing a Stored Procedure from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

How can I execute the below Stored Procedure?

```
create or replace procedure squareOf(x IN OUT NUMBER) is
begin
 x:= x*x;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Massie already mentioned one approach using anonymous block.

Another approach is using bind variable in command line like below -

```
var c number;
exec :c:= 6;
execute squareOf(:c);
print c;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE
  x NUMBER := 6;
BEGIN
  squareOf(x => x );
  dbms_output.put_line( 'X: '|| x );
END;
```

returns 36

Comment: Who gives -1? Why? This is a working answer for this question.

Comment: Please accept my excuses, my down-vote was a mistake and I've just undone it (had to make a bogus edit to unlock it).

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking about 'in SQL Developer' - here's the answer from the IDE perspective.

1. Find your procedure in your database navigation tree.
2. Click or double-click to open in a plsql editor
3. Hit the Execute Button in the toolbar
4. Supply required input values and hit OK to execute
5. Observe any output returned in the bottom log panel

[image: Opening and Executing your PL/SQL Procedure]

[image: The output, in this case, the value of your IN/OUT, X]

Comment: My version of oracle SQL developer doesn't seem to support this. :(

Comment: that feature has existed for years - what version are you running and what happens when you run a SP? inputting the value in the grid for the sp arguments was added in v4 - but you can always edit the anon block

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer  Version 3.2.20.09

Comment: that's how it should work in v3.2 as well. tell me what's not working - or send me an email at jeff.d.smith@oracle.com. or upgrade, takes about 5 minutes to install latest version from OTN